# Add and remove Items on client side with Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been struggling to make an interactive form, in which a viewmodel has a collection of items. I want to dynamically **add/remove** items from that collection.

I've found it difficult to find examples that go to this depth and most of them usually stay on a more straight forward implementation, however I've come across [This post](http://marcofranssen.nl/knockout-js-mappings/) which pretty much explains what i'm doing with this brilliant [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcofranssen/HBKYP/), in which a json is pulled using the knockout mapping pluggin and then mapped.

```
var company;

function PersonViewModel(data) {
  var personMapping = {
    'ignore': ['twitter', 'webpage'],
    'copy': ['age'],
    'lastName': {
      'create': function (options) {
        return ko.observable(options.data.toUpperCase());
      }
    }
  };

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, personMapping, this);

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
  }, this);
}

function CompanyViewModel(data) {
  var companyMapping = {
    'ignore': ['address', 'website'],
    'name': {
      'create': function (options) {
        return ko.observable(options.data.toUpperCase());
      }
    },
    'employees': {
      key: function (data) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.personId);
      },
      create: function (options) {
        return new PersonViewModel(options.data);
      }
    }
  };

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, companyMapping, this);
}
```

What i don't know how to achieve is **how and where** exactly to add the **'addEmployee' and 'removeEmployee'  functions**? and how to bind them to a button?.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since it appears to be the company that owns the employees, I'd think that VM would be the logical place for add and remove functions. Then you add and remove buttons would be bound to those functions. Without more context, it's hard to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical place to add these would be to your `CompanyViewModel`. For example, something like this:

```
function CompanyViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  var companyMapping = {
     // ...as before
  };

  self.addEmployee = function () {
    // as an example, we are just adding a static new employee
    self.employees.push(new PersonViewModel({
      lastName: "new",
      firstName: "employee",
      age: 10
    }));
  }

  // important, with how we are binding the function, we expect the 
  // argument, e, to be the employee to remove
  self.removeEmployee = function (e) {
    self.employees.remove(e);
  }

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, companyMapping, this);
}
```

Add to bind, you can do something like this:

```
<div id="company">
  <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
  <h2>Employees</h2>
  <input type="button" value="add" data-bind="click: addEmployee" />
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Full name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: fullName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="x" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Which will add an `add` button as well as a remove `x` button to each employee which calls the `removeEmployee` function on the parent `CompanyViewModel` passing in the current employee.

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBKYP/199/)

Comment: Thank you!, it works the way I wanted, just a couple questions now, is this the ideal way to do it when you have to add items to a child object? and second, it is not clear to me why the ko.applyBindings is being used so many times (3 times overall)

Comment: First, ` is this the ideal way to do it when you have to add items to a child object?` It's not the only way, but it would be the way most people would do it. You are operating on a collection owned by the `CompanyViewModel`, so it makes sense that those functions would *belong* to the `CompanyViewModel`. Second, I only see one `ko.applyBindings`.

Comment: sorry i meant, ko.mapping.fromJS instead of the ko.applyBindings, i thought that the former should be used only once as well as the latter. and thanks! i've got it working now they way i wanted.

Comment: `ko.mapping.fromJS` is used multiple times because it's mapping different sections of your original object. So in `CompanyViewModel` you have a call to `ko.mapping.fromJS` that maps the `CompanyViewModel` properties. In the settings for that you have a `create` function for `employees` that creates your `PersonViewModel`. The thing passed to that constructor is the fragment of the original JS object, so it needs mapping too, which happens inside `PersonViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You would add those functions to your `CompanyViewModel`.

**CompanyViewModel**

```
...
this.addEmployee = function () {
    this.employees.push(new PersonViewModel({
        firstName: 'New',
        lastName: 'Employee',
        age: 777,
    }));
};
this.removeEmployee = function () {
    this.employees.pop();
};
```

**HTML**

```
....
<div data-bind="click: addEmployee">Add Employee</div>
<div data-bind="click: removeEmployee">Remove Employee</div>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HBKYP/198/

Comment: There is no control here however as to what Employee you are removing. You are simply removing the last added

Comment: I'd assume they want to remove a *specific* employee and not just pop off the last guy added.

Comment: That requirement was not specified. The question only asked *where* these functions should be added.

Comment: Thank you CrimsonChris, you're right, i didn't specify it in the question, my bad. you're code has given me some ideas now, thanks again!